# Python: Extract block of code from HTML document?

Tags: python, html, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to extract blocks of code from an HTML document and save them to a Markdown file with Python. I'm stumped because the HTML document numbers each line of code and I need to remove them to make the code appear properly in the Markdown file. When I use `re.sub(\d+\n)`to remove line numbers it causes lines of code that end in a number to have deletions since they too also match the pattern. For example, `2\n` just before the start of line 29 in my code in the string below gets deleted. That 2 character belongs to the end of line 28 of the code and it shouldn't be deleted.

The relevant string from the HTML page is:

> "1\nclass Solution:\n2\n    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> float:\n3\n        if len(nums1) > len(nums2):\n4\n            nums1, nums2 = nums2, nums1\n5\n        # Lengths of two arrays\n6\n        m = len(nums1)\n7\n        n = len(nums2)\n8\n        # Pointers for binary search\n9\n        start = 0\n10\n        end = m\n11\n        # Binary search starts from here\n12\n        while start <= end:\n13\n            # Partition indices for both the arrays\n14\n            partition_nums1 = (start + end) // 2\n15\n            partition_nums2 = (m + n + 1) // 2 - partition_nums1\n16\n            # Edge cases\n17\n            # If there are no elements left on the left side after partition\n18\n            maxLeftNums1 = -sys.maxsize if partition_nums1 == 0 else nums1[partition_nums1 - 1]\n19\n            # If there are no elements left on the right side after partition\n20\n            minRightNums1 = sys.maxsize if partition_nums1 == m else nums1[partition_nums1]\n21\n            # Similarly for nums2\n22\n            maxLeftNums2 = -sys.maxsize if partition_nums2 == 0 else nums2[partition_nums2 - 1]\n23\n            minRightNums2 = sys.maxsize if partition_nums2 == n else nums2[partition_nums2]\n24\n            # Check if we have found the match\n25\n            if maxLeftNums1 <= minRightNums2 and maxLeftNums2 <= minRightNums1:\n26\n                # Check if the combined array is of even/odd length\n27\n                if (m + n) % 2 == 0:\n28\n                    return (max(maxLeftNums1, maxLeftNums2) + min(minRightNums1, minRightNums2)) / 2\n29\n                else:\n30\n                    return max(maxLeftNums1, maxLeftNums2)\n31\n            # If we are too far on the right, we need to go to left side\n32\n            elif maxLeftNums1 > minRightNums2:\n33\n                end = partition_nums1 - 1\n34\n            # If we are too far on the left, we need to go to right side\n35\n            else:\n36\n                start = partition_nums1 + 1"

Is there a better way to remove the line numbering or extract the code from the HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to remove are numbers that appear exactly at the beginning of each line, so you could do the following:

```
exp = re.compile(r'^\d+\n', re.MULTILINE)
# obtain code...
code = exp.sub('', code)
```

The `^` at the beginning of the regexp means "match the start of the string". The `re.MULTILINE` flag makes it match the start of all lines in the string.